# Custom Classes in Header files

Tags: c

I've created a header file "foo.h" as well as an source file "bar.c" but can't seem to import bar.c into foo.h.

Is this possible? If so, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You `#include` header files in `.c` files, not the other way around.

(Not clear what your underlying problem is though.) - Oh, and C doesn't have classes.

Comment: Thanks:) But is there any way to add a custom datatype to a .h file then? Or will I have to create a struct?

Comment: `struct`s are the only way to create (proper) custom datatypes in C, and yes they can be put in headers. (I still don't understand what your problem is.)

Comment: You can `#include "other.h"` into "foo.h". You would define the custom datatype in "other.h".

Comment: Thanks. Think I'll go that route then. was trying to create a custom "class" and put it in a header, but kept getting an "Unable to resolve Identifier item" error. Will change to structs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it backwards... `.h` files exist to tell other programs what a `.c` file contains. The `.c` *implements* the things listed in the header.

Then, when a different program wants to use some of the stuff you implemented, they `#include` your header. When it compiles, another program called the *linker* is also run. This connects the functions from the header you used to their implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Importing source files is something that should be avoided, although some compilers allow it.
Regarding the data types, it makes perfectly sense to declare them in the header file.

Comment: I'd wager all compilers *must* allow it. As far as I can tell, distinction between header and implementation files exists only in programmers' minds - to the compiler, both are C source files. Some contain mostly declarations, and some contain definitions as well as declarations (due to the `#include`s being done by the preprocessor, before the compiler sees the code).